# FTP Error 530 user cannot log in

Tags: iis, ftp, windows-server-2019

We've got a strange problem. Our FTP-site was configured right and everything was good with no errors until last week. But now when we try to connect to server we see this error. It is NOT error about "Home Directory Inaccessible" but is about "An error occurred during the authentication process".

What we've tried:

- reboot server
- recreate ftp-site
- create new user specially for ftp
- reinstall FTP server role (FTP service/FTP extensibility)

FTP-site settings:

[image]

[image]

Trying to connect:

[image]

Log file entry:

````
2023-07-13 07:41:25 (user_ip) 65525 - FTPSVC2 WIN-LIVFRVQFMKO - (server_ip) 21 USER Administrator 331 0 0 6788f5fb-b0fd-4b13-b722-2ac6e686acac - -
2023-07-13 07:41:25 (user_ip) 65525 - FTPSVC2 WIN-LIVFRVQFMKO - (server_ip) 21 PASS *** 530 1326 41 6788f5fb-b0fd-4b13-b722-2ac6e686acac - An+error+occurred+during+the+authentication+process.
2023-07-13 07:41:26 (user_ip) 65525 - FTPSVC2 WIN-LIVFRVQFMKO - (server_ip) 21 QUIT - 221 0 0 6788f5fb-b0fd-4b13-b722-2ac6e686acac - -
2023-07-13 07:41:26 (user_ip) 65525 - FTPSVC2 WIN-LIVFRVQFMKO - (server_ip) 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 6788f5fb-b0fd-4b13-b722-2ac6e686acac - -```
````

Comment: `until last week` so, what happened last week

Comment: We didn't change anything. About a week ago we used FTP and everything was ok.

Comment: `We didn't change anything` then it should still work. Computers don't change the way they work depending on what week it is. Something has changed, perhaps an automatic update

Comment: I understand that nothing will change without changing the settings. It is remote VDS for our projects. I asked our hosting provider. The said they changed nothing. Anyway we cannot figure out how to resolve authentication process error.

Comment: check the recent windows updates, then research what they did to your system - clearly, if nobody has changed anything, it stands to reason that a cursed windows update is causing this issue